# C# EqualityComparer

Tags: c#, equals

Что такое `EqualityComparer`, почему у него есть свойство `Default`? Зачем это? Я ведь могу просто использовать обычный метод `Equals`.

Comment: Например чтобы скормить его словарю https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1?view=net-5.0. Вы можете переопределить Equals у своего класса, но например не можете это сделать для string.

Comment: @aepot, А в чем тогда отличие ```EqualityComperer<T>.Default.Equals(t1, t2)``` от ```t1.Equals(t2)```?

Comment: Зависит от T. Если речь о кастомных классах, то функциональной разницы нет.

Comment: Если у вас есть метод, принимающий `EqualityComparer`, то можно передать в него либо собственный компаратор, либо `Default`. Если бы не было этого дефолтного, то пришлось бы писать его самому или создавать перегрузку метода, не принимающего компаратор, а в нём использовать `Equals`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EqualityComparer нужен для сравнения классов на основе заданного алгоритма.
Default - автоматически сгенерированный компаратор, для вашего `<T>`. (тут могу ошибаться, не пользовался)

Пример:

```
//пример класса Person с свойством возраста Age
class Person
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
//создадим компаратор, который сравнивает возраст Age у класса Person
class PersonAgeComparer : EqualityComparer<Person>
{
    public override bool Equals(Person b1, Person b2)
    {
        if (b1 == null && b2 == null)
            return true;
        else if (b1 == null || b2 == null)
            return false;
        return b1.Age == b2.Age;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode(Person bx)
    {
        int hCode = bx.Age;
        return hCode.GetHashCode();
    }
}
//создадим для примера 3 экземпляра класса, у двух возраст Age совпадает
Person p1 = new Person() { Name = "Jack", Age = 20 };
Person p2 = new Person() { Name = "Ben", Age = 25 };
Person p3 = new Person() { Name = "Steve", Age = 25 };
List<PersonHumans = new List<Person>() { p1, p2, p3 };
//сгруппируем по возрасту, с использованием копраратора, который создали ранее
var groups = Humans.GroupBy(g => g, new PersonAgeComparer());
foreach(var g in groups)
{
    WriteLine("Age: "+ g.Key.Age);
    g.ToList<Person>().ForEach(a => WriteLine(a.Name));
    WriteLine("");
}
```

Вывод:

```
Age: 20
Jack

Age: 25
Ben
Steve
```

Пример и компаратор простые, просто как пример использования.
Суть в том, что внутри компаратора можно рисовать любые критерии сравнения, на основе любых полей, добавляя любые алгоритмы в метод Equals.
А т.к. сам исходный класс от компаратора не зависит - вам ничего не мешает завести любое колличество разнообразных компараторов и в зависимости от ситуации использовать нужный.
И ещё много чего не сказанного, т.к. возможностей куда больше, ибо это просто класс, оформленный по определённым правилам, делать с ним вы можете что угодно.